# moving object when mouse move in as3

Tags: flash

i made a flash application but my problem is as follow
i have a movie clip and i want to show it when user mouse over to any image of background and also i want same clip follow the mouse cursor.how to do so.
Thank you

Comment: Do you have a link, showing this example?

Comment: Maybe this is what you want. http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3masking/

Answer (score 1):

put 3 movieclip on the stage
name first mc1, then mc2 annd finally mouse_mc

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, _onMouseMove );
            mouse_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
            mc1.alpha = 0;
            mc2.alpha = 0;
        }
        private function _onMouseMove (event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(event.target is MovieClip)
            {
                var target:MovieClip = (event.target as MovieClip);
                if(target.alpha == 0){
                    target.alpha = 1;               
                }
                //trace( (event.target as MovieClip).name );                
            }       

            // follow mouse
            mouse_mc.x = mouseX;
            mouse_mc.y = mouseY;

            event.updateAfterEvent();
        }
    }
}
```

this will make mouse_mc follow your mouse and reveal hidden movieclip on roll over.

for a perfect follow mouse you can also use native cursor
http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-setting-a-native-cursor-using-flash-player-10-2/

enjoy